# Rails form error messages on virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `car` model `belongs_to :policy`.

However, I don't set the `policy` directly: I set it via a virtual attribute / custom setter method called `new_policy`. So in my form, I have:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :new_policy, @new_policy do |policy_form|
    = policy_form.error_notification
```

But the `error_notification` doesn't work for that part of the form, and the inline errors don't show up, even though the `@new_policy` data persists after a failed submit attempt. (No errors are displayed, although the `car` model's `error_notification` alerts the user to the presence of errors.) Is there a way to get the `error_notification` helper to work with the `@new_policy` object? How can I get the errors to show up inline?

Also, my `car` model does not `accepts_nested_attributes_for :policy` since I set `policy` via the virtual attribute. When everything is filled in correctly, everything works as expected.